# EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generate Separate Folders

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, code-first, poco, reverse

EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator do the code generation like this
[image: default generated classes]
Can we create a separate folder for repository, interfaces, configurations and POCO entities by changing tt file. at the moment all the classes generate on root of the application. can we create classes with folders like this.
[image: expected way to generate]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use these namespaces to specify where the different elements now live. These may even be in different assemblies.
Please note this does not create the files in these locations, it only adds a `using` statement to say where they are.

If you have a subscription, I show how this works on the [plural sight course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/code-first-entity-framework-legacy-databases)

The way to do this is to add the "EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator" into each of these folders.
Then set the .tt to only generate the relevant section you need by setting

```
 ElementsToGenerate = Elements.Poco; in your Entity folder,
 ElementsToGenerate = Elements.Context | Elements.UnitOfWork; in your Context folder,
 ElementsToGenerate = Elements.PocoConfiguration; in your Maps folder.
 PocoNamespace = "YourProject.Entities";
 ContextNamespace = "YourProject.Context";
 UnitOfWorkNamespace = "YourProject.Context";   
 PocoConfigurationNamespace = "YourProject.Maps";
```

Comment: I added this long time ago and you have given the answer at codeplex anyway this should be the answer for other who might need.

Comment: Pluralsight costs money :P
Does this mean that I have to open and save the .tt file in each folder if I want to update from the database?

Comment: @HomrZodyssey Yes it does :-) There is a good Q+A section I monitor over at https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838

Comment: Way late here, but you can do Build > Transform All T4 Templates... There's no need to manually trigger them individually.